# Ansible inventory.aws_ec2.yml tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Can someone please explain how to defined value in the inventory.aws_ec2.yml file?

I want to execute ansible-playbook on the below mentiond tags instances. Where I need to defined Environment:stage in inventory.aws_ec2.yml. *i.e. in key or in prefix?*

```
      tags:
        Environment: stage
```

Below is inventory.aws_ec2.yml file.

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-2
  - us-west-2

keyed_groups:
  # Add hosts to tag name groups
  #  - key: tags.Role
  #    prefix: role_
  #    separator: ""
  - key: tags.Environment
    prefix: stage
    separator: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `key: tags.Environment` by each different value of this tag will be created a group in ansible, `prefix` is to add a prefix to the name of each of groups created in ansible (I recommend you in this case use `"Environment"`) and `separator` is to add characters between the prefix and the value of the tags (by default is "_"). A way to write your aws_ec2.yml is

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-2
  - us-west-2

keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.Environment
    prefix: Environment
    separator: "_"
```

For example, if you have 4 ec2 instances with tag: Environment=stage and 2 ec2 instances with tag: Environment=prod, you'll have two groups in ansible, `Environment_stage` and `Environment_prod` then you could create your playbook in this way

```
- name: Testing my groups
  hosts: Environment_stage
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Debug my ec2 instances
    debug:
      msg: "hostname: {{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. I tried provided solution and it's work as per expectation.